# How do I format a number to 2 d.p when referring to many? HTML5

Tags: html

So I'm trying to create a simple form once a user is logged in, a user needs to say how much they want to raise and their target number, I only want to limit it to 2 d.p. I also want to have the "$" sign in the very beginning on the left hovering but not interferring just for decoration, and fornthe sign to be persistent.

`

```html
 <p> <label>
 How much are you trying to raise? <input type="number" placeholder="Enter target amount" min=1 step="any" name="target">
 </label> </p>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you look for something like that? You bind an eventListener to the input field and as soon as a number has been entered you can format the number with a regex and put a $ sign in front of it for the output.

```js
function format1(n, currency) {
  n = parseInt(n);
  return currency + n.toFixed(2).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
    return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
  });
}


const i = document.getElementById('target');
i.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  var number = document.getElementById('target').value;
  console.log( format1( number, '$') )
})
```

```html
 <p> <label>
 How much are you trying to raise? <input type="number" placeholder="Enter target amount" id="target" min=1 step="any" name="target">
 </label> </p>
```

### UPDATE

Ok. I have only now realized that it is not such a simple task to put the formatted number back into the input. Because it is a formatted string. I have now once the value in the input (fromartierter string) and then I have the number in a data attribute of the input deposited. With this I work. I have added: 1. that only numbers are accepted, 2. delete key deletes 3. dollar sign is now placed with CSS in the input field. You just need to add some logic when deleting all numbers one by one, that it makes the NaN an empty string at 0 characters.

So sorry for the first too fast answer. This is already a bigger deal.

```js
function format(n) {
  n = parseInt(n);
  return n.toFixed(2).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
    return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
  });
}


const i = document.getElementById('target');
i.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {  
  const obj = document.getElementById('target');
  const number = (obj.getAttribute('data-store'));  
  const keynum = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  
  if (String.fromCharCode(keynum).replace(/[^\d]/,'') == '') {
    obj.value = format( number )
  }
  
  if (e.keyCode == 8) {     
    let newNumber = number.substring(0, number.length - 1);
     
    obj.setAttribute('data-store', newNumber)
    obj.value = format( newNumber )
    return;
  }
  
      
  const pressed = (String.fromCharCode(keynum))  
  const con = number == '0' ? pressed : number + pressed;
  console.log('pair', [number, pressed, con, format( con )])    
  obj.value = format( con );
  obj.setAttribute('data-store', con)
})
```

```css
.currency {
  position:absolute; margin-left: 1px; margin-top:1px;
}

.inp-amount {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<p> <label>
 How much are you trying to raise? 
   <span class="currency">$</span>
   <input data-store="0" class="inp-amount" type="text" placeholder="  Enter target amount" id="target" min=1 step="any" name="target">
 </label></p>
```

Comment: Will try this way and let you know, however, this is in javascript. how would I translate or implement or import it in HTML5

Comment: @TobiFayemi I updated my answear ;-)